# Eliminate 404 error

Tags: ppa

I added a PPA and every time I run `apt-get update` the Bash reminds me of my failure:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/whatever/
etcetera/.../.../Packages  404  Not Found
```

I want to know if there is a way to stop seeing it.

Comment: assuming you don't want to remove the ppa?

Comment: @Zanna Yes, I do want to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to stop seeing this, you have to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or removing the proper file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, for that open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and check if it is in the `sources.list` file by typing:

```
less /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If it is a line in here which got added you can edit the `sources.list` by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If its not there you might want to check the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory by listing the contents of that directory with:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

If your line with the `ppa` shows there find the corresponding list file and remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<ppa-file-name-which-is-involved>.list
```

Of course if you not want to remove this file but instead correct it you can edit it with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<ppa-file-name-which-is-involved>.list
```